# sorted is duplicating entries

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I want to sort a nested list by the numerical values in the second entry of the nested lsits.

```
name= ['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh']
score = [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]

mylist = [[title, grade] for title in name for grade in score]
test = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

But this duplicates entries for some reason.  Why doesn't it just sort the list by the second entries in the nested lists?

```
 test
    [['Harry', 37.2], ['Berry', 37.2], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 37.2], ['Harsh', 37.2], `['Harry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.21], ['Akriti', 37.21], ['Akriti', 37.21], ['Harsh', 37.21], ['Harsh', 37.21], ['Harry', 39.0], ['Berry', 39.0], ['Tina', 39.0], ['Akriti', 39.0], ['Harsh', 39.0], ['Harry', 41.0], ['Berry', 41.0], ['Tina', 41.0], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 41.0]]`
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with the sorting - look at what `[[title, grade] for title in name for grade in score]` creates. It's equivalent to a _nested loop_, you want `zip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `zip`:

```
>>> name= ['Harry', 'Berry', 'Tina', 'Akriti', 'Harsh']
>>> score = [37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 41.0, 39.0]
>>> sorted(zip(score, name))
[(37.2, 'Tina'), (37.21, 'Berry'), (37.21, 'Harry'), (39.0, 'Harsh'), (41.0, 'Akriti')]
```

Think of `zip` as adding the two lists together:

```
[(score[0], name[0]), (score[1], name[1]), ...]
```

whereas the nested comprehension you were doing is more like multiplying them:

```
[[name[0], score[0]], [name[1], score[0]], [name[2], score[0], ..., [name[0], score[1]], [name[1], score[1]], [name[2], score[1], ...]
```

Comment: So funnily enough this actually does accomplish what the task is asking me to do on hacker rank but because of the way they've rigged up the input it doesn't work.  Super frustrating to say the least.

Comment: @AngusCampbell Where at hacker rank is it?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem, I've nearly got my own solution working, just need to get the names to come out in the order they want.

Comment: So how does it not work? How is the input "rigged up"? And given that the input alternates between name and score and the provided code already reads in pairs, why do you create two lists at all, instead of one list of pairs right away?

Answer (score 0):

Your iterating twice.

```
# using enumerate
mylist = [[title, score[ind]] for ind, title in eunmerate(name)]

# Using zip
mylist = zip(name, score)
```